# AES mode scheme feedback

Tags: aes

I've been studying encryption on a hobby basis, and wanted to know if I got this basic cypher construction right (this is another experiment, see the AES ECB experiment thread earlier).

Encryption:

1. XOR plain text block, initialization vector and counter together.
2. AES resulting block.
3. Increment counter.
4. Goto 1 until all plain text blocks are done.

Authentication tag:

1. Sha256 cipher text.
2. AES resulting hash using authentication key.

Comment: As to the first part, this will answer your question: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14782/why-does-ctr-mode-xor-the-plaintext-into-the-output-of-the-block-cipher-rather-t/14785#14785

Comment: For the second part, see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/is-the-encryption-of-a-hash-a-good-mac

Comment: Yeah, those posts explain it all. Thanks. It sure is easy to get this wrong.

Comment: A common truth is: It is easy to design a scheme you can't break yourself. But it is an entirely different matter to design a scheme, which no one can break.